# Accidentaly deleted openshift object: LinstorController

Tags: openshift-4

I have accidentally deleted LinstorController instance from Linstor Operator by Openshift console.

Fortunatelly it was not deleted because LinstorSatelliteSet exists.

Please see the error:
`oc describe linstorcontroller/linstor`

...
errors:
- >-
temporary error: timeout=60000000000, error=controller controller still
has active satellites which must be cleared before deletion:
[txl4201.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk txl4202.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk
txl4203.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk txl4204.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk
txl4205.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk txl4301.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk
txl4302.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk txl4303.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk
txl4304.nprod01.ocp.vub.sk]

Is it possible to recover from this state and how?

Openshift ver. 4.8.29
Linstor Operator ver. 1.5.1
Linstor controller version 1.13.0; GIT-hash: 37c02e20aa52f26ef28ce4464925d9e53327171c

Thank you in advance

Otto Bodor

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resulted by deleting the finalizers following Red Hat knowledgebase: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2317401 of the deleted LinstorController object `oc patch linstorcontrollers linstor --type='merge' -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'` and recreating it by the original yaml file again.
The lucky thing was LinstorController did not initialized its db but reused it.
Everythings is working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).